# Submit button does not work after bootstrap styling in DJANGO

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms, django-templates, mdbootstrap

After I apply mdbootstrap, submit button function is broken. Nothing happens when i clicked.

my view.py code:

```
def scanDetail(request,scan_pk):

context = {
    bla bla bla
}
if request.method == 'GET':
    return render(request, 'test/scanDetail.html',context)
else:
    selected_values = request.POST.getlist('falsePositive')
    **if request.POST.get("save"):**
        for scan in scanResults:
            if request.POST.get("a"+str(scan.id)) == "clicked":
                scan.falsePositive = True
            else:
                scan.falsePositive = False
            scan.save()

    return redirect('scAppv2:currentSc')
```

here is my template:

```
 {% for scan in xxxx %}
        <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <tr>
        <td>
        {% if scan.falsePositive == True %}
    <input type="checkbox" name="c{{ scan.id }}" value="clicked" checked />
        {% else %}
        <input type="checkbox" name="c{{ scan.id }}" value="clicked" />
        {% endif %}
        </td>
        <td>{{ scan.a }}</td>
        <td>{{ scan.b }}</td>
        <td>{{ scan.c }}</td>
        <td>{{ scan.d }}</td>
        </tr>

    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    </table>
<br>
    **<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" name= "save" value="save" />SAVE</button>**
        </form>
```

If i delete below code, everything goes to nice, and submit works. But i did not understand rootcause.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">

     $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#scanDetailMainTable').DataTable({
    "paging": false // false to disable pagination (or any other option)
  });
  $('.dataTables_length').addClass('bs-select');
});


  </script>
```

Please help me anyone? Thanks.

Comment: Do you get any errors shown in the web console when the submit button doesn't work?

Comment: And try changing this `"paging": false` to true in JS to check if this is caused by pagination.

Comment: I do not get any error, I also checked Develeper tools in Chrome. When i clicked submit, anything happens.

Comment: I disable paging false. When i do paging again, nothing happens

Comment: Besides, when i cut below code, to above my table, submit is work but funcionality was broken, anything select.  <form method="POST"">
        {% csrf_token %}